# Apache HIVE query getting exception

Tags: hadoop, hive

I was trying very simple Hive query.

```
hive> create table emp(eid int, name string, sal int, dno int, gender string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';

hive> load data local inpath 'emp.txt' into table emp;

hive> select * from emp;
```

== Here now i am getting error==

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException:
>   Could not obtain block:
>   BP-954485364-127.0.1.1-1535724697104:blk_1073741891_1067
>   file=/user/hive/warehouse/emp1/emp_tab Time taken: 0.156 seconds

This query is working for me few days back .. now its not working . Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an HDFS issue, not Hive per se. Check your filesystem with `hdfs fsck /` for the whole filesystem, or `hdfs fsck /user/hive/warehouse/emp1` for the directory in your message.

This might tell you if a block is missing, corrupted, replicating. Depending on the output the correcting action might be different.

Comment: hdfs fsck  /user/hive/warehouse/emp1;
Connecting to namenode via http://localhost:50070/fsck?ugi=chenna&path=%2Fuser%2Fhive%2Fwarehouse%2Femp1
FSCK started by chenna (auth:SIMPLE) from /127.0.0.1 for path /user/hive/warehouse/emp1 at Wed Jan 09 15:17:24 IST 2019
.
/user/hive/warehouse/emp1/emp.txt: CORRUPT blockpool BP-954485364-127.0.1.1-1535724697104 block blk_1073742181

/user/hive/warehouse/emp1/emp.txt: MISSING 1 blocks of total size 216 B..
/user/hive/warehouse/emp1/emp_tab: CORRUPT blockpool BP-954485364-127.0.1.1-1535724697104 block blk_1073741891

Comment: /user/hive/warehouse/emp1/emp_tab: MISSING 1 blocks of total size 86 B.Status: CORRUPT
 Total size: 302 B
 Total dirs: 1
 Total files: 2
 Total symlinks:  0
 Total blocks (validated): 2 (avg. block size 151 B)
  ********************************
  UNDER MIN REPL'D BLOCKS: 2 (100.0 %)
  dfs.namenode.replication.min: 1
  CORRUPT FILES: 2
  MISSING BLOCKS: 2
  MISSING SIZE:  302 B
  CORRUPT BLOCKS:  2
  ********************************

Comment: ********************************
 Minimally replicated blocks: 0 (0.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks: 0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks: 0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:  0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor: 1
 Average block replication: 0.0
 Corrupt blocks:  2
 Missing replicas:  0
 Number of data-nodes:  1
 Number of racks:  1
FSCK ended at Wed Jan 09 15:17:24 IST 2019 in 1 milliseconds


The filesystem under path '/user/hive/warehouse/emp1' is CORRUPT